# Calling x64 C++ DLL from C#, process hangs (update)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, 64-bit

I'm porting a managed C++ DLL (MecDll) from x86 to x64.
test code in C#:

```
[DllImport("test.dll"), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern int getseven();
[DllImport("MecDll.dll"), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern int getsevenmec();

Console.WriteLine("{0}" , getseven() );
Console.WriteLine("{0}" , getsevenmec() );
```

code in test.dll:

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall getseven() {
return 7;
}
}
```

Code added to MecDll.dll:

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall getsevenmec() {
return 8;
}
}
```

When I run the test, I get the 7 printed from the test.dll and then process just hangs on a black window.
I see in process explorer that the dll is loaded.

The test C# code is compiled with any CPU and the DLL's with x64.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: I did, the same happens, i put a break point at the function call, it breaks, i press F11 and nothing

Comment: Update, I tried to call the DLL from C++ code, the code hangs on loading the DLL.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: I did, the same happens, i put a break point at the function call, it breaks, i press F11 and nothing

Comment: do "break all" then look at what the threads are doing.

Comment: doesn't help, it stops at the load library function

Comment: Looks like loader deadlock then. Are you calling the function from another DLL while that DLL is in the process of being loaded?

Comment: Also: What are the **other** threads doing? What else is on the call stack? You need to gather information - there is no way to answer this question without information.

Comment: my test program is the only one loading this dll.
i copied this dll and the test program to a different computer and the same happens so nobody else is accessing it.

i have no idea what the threads are, all i'm running is import library and thats it, this is the function that opens threads, not me.
what other data can i gather?

thanks for helping btw

Comment: The debugger will tell you what all the threads in the process are doing, including the hanging thread. That's what the debugger is for.

Comment: Look, run it up. Wait for the hang, then press the "break" button on the toolbar. Then use the "threads" window under the menu Debug->Windows to see all the threads. You can switch focus to each thread in turn and see what it is doing right now, and look at the call stack to see how it got there.

Comment: this was really helpful, now i see that it hangs on the dll code and not in the OS.
the problem is still weird, the line of code that makes the difference is:

#define TIMEOUT -108
if (m_ConnectionId != TIMEOUT && (m_ConnectionId & 0x80000000))


m_ConnectionId  is a socket.

this if statment is taken in x64 and not taken in x86.
the value of m_ConnectionId  in both cases is 0xffffff94 witch is -108

any idea why the different behavior in x64 and x86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a constructor of a static variable, inside the constructor there was a == between a socket and a defined negative number, adding (DWORD) before the negative number to the define fixed the issue.
thanks Ben